# Problemas de conexion a API con nodeJS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, backend

Estoy empezando a trabajar en el backend de una SPA tengo la siguiente conexion con la pokeAPi pero al momento de darle al get en postman me esta retornando un objeto vacio, verifique la conexion con un console.log('Hola') enviando la respuesta y se esta dando pero no logro consumir de la API la información con el fetch, no logro ver el error o si estoy omitiendo algo, la idea es traer la info de la API para almacenar los datos que necesito en la DB y luego pasarsela al front

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const { Pokemon, Type } = require('../db'); //Modelos

const router = Router();

// Configurar los routers

router.get('/pokemons', async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
        .then(data => data.json()
        ).then(res.send(response))
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

El segundo `.then` está mal. Debería estar despues de `data.json()`:

```
await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon').then(data => {
    data.json().then(response => {
        res.send(response)
    })
})
```

Comment: Me tira un error indicando que fetch no esta definido


W:\Documentos\Henry Academy\PokemonPI\api\src\routes\index.js:26
  await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon').then(data => {
  ^

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined        
    at W:\Documentos\Henry Academy\PokemonPI\api\src\routes\index.js:26:3

Comment: @WillDiaz Eso es un problema diferente. `fetch` no viene por defecto en node pero puedes instalar `node-fetch` o usar una librería como [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) (yo recomiendo usar axios)